# Python and SQL Server - _pymssql.ProgrammingError: (208, b"Invalid object name X. DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16 ..)

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I want to fetch data from a MSSQL Server (Microsoft SQL Server 2017) via Python (3.8.6) and the pymssql library (2.2.7).

The tables are in the dbo Schema of database **A**, the default database of the user is **master**.

By using the following code, I am able to fetch data from most of the tables:

```py
import pymssql

# Connect to the database - dont mind the fake server, pw and other creds, database='A'
conn = pymssql.connect(
  server='localhost', 
  user='sa', 
  password='1234', 
  database='A', 
  port=8888
)

# Create a cursor
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Execute a SELECT statement++++
c = cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbo.KHKBookings")

results = cursor.fetchall()

# Iterate over the results and print each row
for row in results:
    print(row)

# Close the cursor and connection
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

While it works for the example table **KHKBookings**, it does not for another one called **icZGBookings**, which is in the same database and also in dbo schema. I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "src\pymssql_pymssql.pyx",
> line 459, in pymssql._pymssql.Cursor.execute   File
> "src\pymssql_mssql.pyx", line 1087, in
> pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query   File
> "src\pymssql_mssql.pyx", line 1118, in
> pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query   File
> "src\pymssql_mssql.pyx", line 1251, in
> pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_and_run_query   File
> "src\pymssql_mssql.pyx", line 1789, in
> pymssql._mssql.check_cancel_and_raise   File "src\pymssql_mssql.pyx",
> line 1835, in pymssql._mssql.raise_MSSQLDatabaseException
> pymssql._mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (208, b"Invalid object name
> 'dbo.icZGBookings'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral
> SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    File "src\pymssql_pymssql.pyx", line 476, in
> pymssql._pymssql.Cursor.execute pymssql._pymssql.ProgrammingError:
> (208, b"Invalid object name 'dbo.icZGBookings'.DB-Lib error message
> 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the
> SQL Server\n")

So we are not finding the table, I can also make up a table and get the same error.

Adding the Database to the query didnt help either:
`SELECT TOP 10 * FROM A.dbo.icZGBookings`

But why is that so? I cant figure it out, because the table **icZGBookings** exists.
I can see and query it with the same user **sa** in MSSQL Server Management Studio in the database **A** and schema **dbo**.

I even altered the default database for that user from **master** to **A**, but that didnt help either.
We should not need to do that anyway because we specify the database we connect to in the beginning.
The **master** database **dbo** schema is empty anyway and should have not worked for the other tables too.

So, why cant I query it via Python?

I compared the values of the two tables with the following query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p
ON t.object_id = p.object_id
WHERE t.name in ('KHKBookings', 'icZGBookings')
```

The values are not different besides the object_ids, index_ids, and dates of course.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Port 8888 is a very unusual port number for an SQL Server instance. Is it possible that you have multiple instances of SQL Server installed... and that only one of them has a copy of the `A` database with the `dbo.icZGBookings` table?

Comment: hmm good point.  I will check that. 
Indeed I use via Python an IP and in Studio a host address like **IC-1001\ZG**. The port was a fake port

Comment: @AlwaysLearning so I checked and it should be the same server as another tool (DataVirtuality) which has a connection to the same server and can pull the tables.
While I dont know what DataVirtuality is doing different, I still cant see and fetch those tables via Python. Also I tried HeidiSQL tool to access the MSSQL directly and query it - there I can also not see those tables. Super strange - but it must be then some kind of connection settings that prevent me? Because in the DataVirtuality tool it works.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using the `sa` login in your applications. The `sa` login is the System Administrator and has carte blanche access to everything in the instance so you want to protect those credentials from prying eyes. Since the `sa` login has carte blanche access to everything if you cannot see the `icZGBookings` table on a particular instance then it simply doesn't exist there, which brings us back to: `IC-1001\ZG` must be a different instance than `localhost` on port `8888`.

Comment: thanks @AlwaysLearning will change the user. I contacted the company (3rd party...) that set the MSSQL up and they cant solve the problem either...
Interesting point: accessing the MSSQL via host address works, accessing it via IP doesnt show the tables. The only reason can be here that its a different instance, right?  Or can there be different access rights depending if using IP or DNS?

Comment: The SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager tool allows you to configure the server protocols for each SQL Server instance installed on the machine. While it would be possible to configure different instances to be listening on the same port, but different addresses (so one is listening on the machine IP:8888, another on 127.0.0.1:8888, for example), that would be extremely unusual and confusing.